# Query for last successful build number in Jenkins with change

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Example:

```
32 - fail
31 - stable no change (triggered by parent)
30 - stable with changes
29 - fail 
...
```

I want a query to return `30`

---

So far what I got:

**To query the last stable build number:**

`http://jenkins/job/project_name/lastStableBuild/buildNumber`

This returns `31`. Not exactly what I need.

**To check if this build has changes, the only way I know is :**

`http://jenkins/job/project_name/31/api/json`

Then I need to go inside the huge JSON and check if any item in changeSet > items.

---

Is there a easier way to query for the latest stable build with changes (30) ?

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins' [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) with:

```
http://jenkins/job/<your job>/<build no>/api/xml
```

supports XPath, too:

> #### XPath selection
>
> The XML API supports a selection by XPath by using the query parameter 'xpath'. This is convenient for extracting information in environments where XML manipulation is tedious (such as shell script.) See issue [#626](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-626) for an example of how to use this.
> See .../api/ on your Jenkins server for more up-to-date details.